# Devise edit_user_registration_path routing No routes matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

use edit_user_registration_path i got this error.

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/profile", :action=>"show", :id=>1}

When I run rake routes

edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}

Why it changed to devise/profile?

Comment: Can you paste the code in the view where you call the route helper?